# Passing a list name and an item into a function to search the list. ValueError: substring not found

Tags: python, search, substring

I'm fairly new to Python but am ok with programming (although haven't done any for about 5 years).

I've searched but can't find anything to answer my problem:

I have a number of lists, each with values in them, I'm trying to create a generic function that takes 2 values that searches a list, the 2 values are obviously the list name, and the string to search for in that list:

```
list0 = ["name","date","cat","dog"]
list1 = ["house","chair","table"]
list2 = ["tv","dvd","computer","mouse"]

usersearchlist = raw_input("Enter list name: ")
usersearchitem = raw_input("Enter item to search for: ")

def searchmemory(usersearchlist,usersearchitem):
  return usersearchlist.index(usersearchitem)
```

I then call the function:

```
print "I found", searchmemory(usersearchlist,usersearchitem)
```

I'm getting the "ValueError: substring not found" because the function call is taking the literal string passed into the function and not referencing the value contained inside of it.

Hope that makes sense, am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: Note that having variables named `list1`, `list2`, etc... is a **massive** red flag - wherever you have a situation like that, you should be using a data structure instead of variables.

Comment: that's just my example, don't worry, they have proper names, just simpler for you guys to work out whats going on without having to decode my actual list names!

Comment: My point wasn't the the names were wrong, it's that you have a logical grouping of those items that isn't represented in the code. If you find yourself needing to get variables by name in your code, you should be using a data structure rather than flat variables.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
lists = {"list0" : ["name","date","cat","dog"],
    "list1" : ["house","chair","table"],
    "list2" : ["tv","dvd","computer","mouse"]}

usersearchlist = raw_input("Enter list name: ")
usersearchitem = raw_input("Enter item to search for: ")

def searchmemory(usersearchlist, usersearchitem):
    if (usersearchlist in lists and usersearchitem in lists[usersearchlist]):
        return lists[usersearchlist].index(usersearchitem)
    else:
        return -1
```

This stores all the lists in a dictionary and checks if the value exists first so you shouldn't get a ValueError

Comment: The Pythonic way to do this is to ask for forgiveness rather than permission - instead of checking beforehand if the items are in the lists, `try` it, then `except` the potential exceptions if there is an error.

Comment: @Lattyware and in this case would be `KeyError` and `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to put the lists in a dictionary similar to @SimplyKiwi 's answer.

---

Alternatively, you can also achieve it with [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals):

```
print "I found", searchmemory(globals().get(usersearchlist, []), usersearchitem)
```

Be warned though in this case, you are implicitly giving the user access to all the global variables. In most scenario, this is *not* what you would want the users to be able to do.

Comment: While this is true, I can't stress enough how much of a terrible idea this is.

Comment: @Lattyware I agree with you -- note that I said I'd prefer the other solution. I probably should stress the potential harmfulness of my solution more. Will do that in a bit :)